# Amazon S3 - Cloudfront - Images just randomly get permission denied

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

we have a very strange issue with the images on our websites. From time to time, some images get a permission denied response when our website is requested. These images are in a S3 bucket with CloudFront infront of it to distribute them. Most of the time, everything is working fine, but sometimes just some pictures get these permission denied responses. It's not when we updated or edit these pictures, they are over a year old and untouched since then.
I am pretty new to this topic, so I do not really know how to debug that.
And help is much appreaciated.

This is the permission denied response:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>744ACE32DD6CB88C</RequestId>
<HostId>
Zn6V6lr7qlTyL/b1YAHrkqMqnxYOyfQCvwHSAv+wUDGNkONGb1mJbgKWBWjp4OZUEz/DgfHYtrE=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Regards
Nils

Comment: How frequently? How long does it remain unavailable? I'd probably start by pointing something like Pingdom at one of the problematic URLs and track outages over time for a while - it would be useful info to open a support case with Amazon.

Comment: It disappeared 2 times today alone and they came back without doing anything. Your idea was pretty good, I just setup uptime robot to track the online status of these images. Thank you.

Comment: Pingdom won't tell you anything other than access/no-access. Open a support case and include the RequestID, bucket and key name. Amazon might be able to tell you what happened, but do not wait too long - they do not keep logs forever.

Comment: @JohnHanley Pingdom lets you go to them with "it was unavailable from the following locations at the following specific times" rather than a vague "it doesn't work sometimes" assertion. Good point on not waiting too long, though.